# What is the oldest variety of English in the Americas?

Tags: history, varieties

There are several varieties of the English Language in the Americas, from Alaska to the Falkland Islands. To mention just a few:

- American General and its varieties
- Canadian General
- Bajan
- Falklander
- Newfoundland English
- Guyanese
- Bahamian
- Trinidadian
- Bermudian
- Belizean
- And several other varieties, not to mention dialects, pidgins and creoles.

Some varieties - not mentioned above - may have existed and gone extinct.   Of course languages change all the time.  Barbadian English as it is in the twenty-first century, is not the same as it was when the first English settlers arrived in 1627-1628. Even so, we can consider that Barbadian English was born at that time, even though a language changes and receives influences all the time.  Among those that are neither vulnerable nor endangered, and considering the time when the first settlers arrived, what variety of English has been in the Americas longer than any other?  In other words, where was it that the English Language first arrived in the Americas and is still spoken in 2014 in a way that allows us to call it a variety of English? (not a dialect or pidgin).

Comment: No. They don't have birthdays and they constantly change, just like any language -- especially the creoles. There are no useful sociolinguistic data on how these languages were spoken centuries ago, let alone how much influence they've had on each other. How can one tell "longer than" when one hasta put quotes around "alive and well"? I.e, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: By "alive and well" I obviously mean "not extinct", "not dead", "not endangered", "not vulnerable".

Comment: @Kristina Lopez tchrist Josh61 choster Rory Alsop I've re-written my question and tried to make clearer what I'm asking.  Please, read it and reconsider.

Comment: @Luis I already voted to reopen before your comment even. :)

Comment: @Luis I think you also need to consider the age of the dialect that came to the Americas.  If settlers came from, say, the London area, or anywhere near there, then they probably spoke the most modern dialect.  But some settlers who came from some of the more remote areas of the UK brought with them much older dialects than was spoken at the same time by people in London.  So if you're looking for oldest it's not merely about when settlers first arrived but also the antiquity of the dialect that arrived.  If area B is settled 20 years later but with a dialect 100 years older that matters.

Comment: @Brillig That would be another question, and not exactly what I asked. I would have to rephrase my question once more, and it hasn't even been reopened yet.

Comment: @Brillig The Oxford Companion to the English Language says that "Appalachian English" has been regarded (popularly but incorrectly) as a kind of Elizabethan or Shakespearian English" and then goes on offering data to back it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEWFOUNDLAND ENGLISH**

> According to Margery Fee, Department of English, The University of British Columbia, Vancouver, B.C., Candada, "The English language as used in the island and province of Newfoundland for almost 500 years is the oldest variety in the Americas. It derives primarily from the speech of early settlers from the English West Country and later Ireland, and is the outcome of long, stable settlement and relative remoteness. The isolation, however, should not be overemphasized: The women in these communities were isolated, while the men were not, because they travelled to find seasonal work sealing, logging, and cod-fishing.  Many Newfoundland *townies* have features of pronunciation, grammar, and vocabulary that are distinct from the rest of Canada, and the varied dialects of the *baymen* are possibly the most distinctive in the country.  Because of such factors, the English of Newfoundland is something  more than a dialect of CanE, and can be described as a variety with a standard and dialects of its own." (The Oxford Companion to the English Language, page 689.)

References:

*1*. [Fee,M. Newfoundland English, in "The Oxford Companion to the English Language", Oxford University Press, 1992.](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780192800619.001.0001/acref-9780192800619-e-840?rskey=mUAT9K&result=844)
 *2*. [Story,GM. Dictionary of Newfoundland English. Toronto University Press, 1990.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=XrVbk3EndTcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=dictionary+of+newfoundland+english&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=Lw8iVIKvHcrKggTCo4D4AQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=dictionary%20of%20newfoundland%20english&f=false)

FOR FUN (vídeo) - [A Newfoundland Language Lesson with Mark Critch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqLuIXwsLDw)

PS  [The Oxford Companion to the English Language](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019214183X) says that "Appalachian English" has been regarded (popularly but incorrectly) as a kind of Elizabethan or Shakespearian English" and then goes on offering data to back it up.

Comment: So let's review.  You asked a question obviously fishing for a certain answer, admitted on Sept 3 that your reason for asking the question was because you wanted to see if anyone else thought what Fee said was correct, revised your question when it wasn't producing the answer you wanted, and when despite all this no one particually agreed with Fee, and continued to give you answers that weren't what you were fishing for, you answered it yourself on Sept 24 and awarded yourself the best answer.  Heck, you might as well post it on Wiki next.  Won't make it true though.

Comment: @Brillig  I posted the question on Sept 3rd, edited it on Sept 7th, trying to make clear that I wasn't looking for a dialect. Then I waited 17 days for answers. There was only one and I read it carefully. My question is about a variety of English and not a dialect. Your answer shows research effort and a considerable time spent posting all that.  However it's about a dialect. Believe me, I didn't want to answer the question myself. I'd rather have found a convincing answer about a variety of English.

Comment: @Brillig  And I posted that that was what I was looking for long before I decided to answer the question  myself. I hope such small thing hasn't created any animosity.

Comment: when I posted my long and well-researched answer your question wasn't omitting dialects.  You only made that change after my answer, so you could try to exclude my answer.  But your change is just silly.  All varieties of English can be referred to as dialects.  The varieties you list in your question are no more distinct than the Appalachian variety.  Numerous sources list Newfoundland speach as a dialect.  http://www.dialectatlas.mun.ca/ and  http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/newfoundland-labrador/preserving-changing-dialects-of-newfoundland-and-labrador-1.2251509 for instance.

Comment: @Brillig  When I first posted it, I mentioned "Variety of English" as you can check by on the edit history. When you answered it with the word dialect, I then edited and made it clear that I meant a variety.  And a variety has a standard and dialects of its own, just like Newfoundland English.  If you still have any more comments, then we should go to a chat-room.

Comment: BUT THERE IS ABSOLUTELY NO DIFFERENCE BETWEEN A VARIETY AND A DIALECT.  NEWFOUNDLAND IS A DIALECT.  APPALACHIAN IS A VARIETY.  Google hits for "Newfoundland dialect" 6550.  Google hits for "Newfoundland variety of English"  4.  Google hits for "Newfoundland English" 32.7K.  Google hits for "Appalachian English"  27K versus "Appalachian dialect" 8K.  You changed your answer and excluded Appalachian but then you allowed your answer Newfoundland which is every bit as much a dialect and no more a variety than Appalachian.

Answer (score 8):

There has been research done on this subject.

[The Qualls Concise English Grammar](http://books.google.com/books?id=tjrd5UnFT2gC&pg=PT27&lpg=PT27&dq=oldest+english+dialects+in+americas&source=bl&ots=LQKgqzVNUI&sig=oq8_LdEIdO-p5IaeEtB01MGqIe0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_GoHVMSRDIfxgwSRlYDACg&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=oldest%20english%20dialects%20in%20americas&f=false) claims that:

> "The Appalachian dialect is the oldest of English dialects in British
>   North America..."

This source focuses on populations exceeding 2 million so it includes groups from the USA, Canada, and Jamaica.  It is also interesting to note that Qualls believes that several of the the North American dialects are the oldest in the world, in that they retain so many elements of 16th century usage.

If I wanted, I could post other sources that support other regions like Newfoundland being the *oldest* dialect in North America (and I mean including everything north of of South America).

I could further then get into to the debate of whether the North American dialects are really oldest, and could argue a dialect like that from the Newcastle-upon-Tyne area ('Geordie' accent) is even older since it retains so many elements from the 5th century, as this [blog](http://www.thevoicecafe.net/the-voice-cafe-blog/geordie-the-oldest-english-dialect) claims.

But I don't think that Qualls or the blog about the Geordie accent or any other source I might cite that would argue a different dialect being *oldest* is correct.  I prefer the description given by this [Brief History of the English Language](http://www.anglik.net/englishlanguagehistory.htm).

> Also significant beginning around 1600 AD was the English colonization
>   of North America and the subsequent creation of American English. Some
>   pronunciations and usages "froze" when they reached the American
>   shore. In certain respects, some varieties of American English are
>   closer to the English of Shakespeare than modern Standard English
>   ('English English' or as it is often incorrectly termed 'British
>   English') is. Some "Americanisms" are actually originally English
>   English expressions that were preserved in the colonies while lost at
>   home (e.g., *fall* as a synonym for autumn, *trash* for rubbish, and *loan*
>   as a verb instead of lend).
>
> The American dialect also served as the route of introduction for many
>   native American words into the English language. Most often, these
>   were place names like *Mississippi*, *Roanoke*, and *Iowa*. Indian-sounding
>   names like Idaho were sometimes created that had no native-American
>   roots. But, names for other things besides places were also common.
>   *Raccoon*, *tomato*, *canoe*, *barbecue*, *savanna*, and *hickory* have native
>   American roots, although in many cases the original Indian words were
>   mangled almost beyond recognition.
>
> Spanish has also been great influence on American English. *Mustang*,
>   *canyon*, *ranch*, *stampede*, and *vigilante* are all examples of Spanish
>   words that made their way into English through the settlement of the
>   American West.
>
> A lesser number of words have entered American English from French and
>   West African languages.

For any of the varieties and dialects that exist in North America, some (like Qualls) may try to argue that because certain historical words persist in that dialect, that the dialect is *older*, but what no one can deny is that all English dialects around the world include many newer words which have been introduced to the language over time, and these newer words are spoken side-by-side with the older words, so none of the dialects is really the same as was spoken in historical times.

If interested in further investigation, this [source](http://aschmann.net/AmEng/#LargeMap) provides a lot of current information on North American dialects in the USA and Canada, in how they differ and where they are located, but not so much their date of origin.

Comment: Appalachia and Newfoundland also happen to be among the places in North America that retain the strongest connection to traditional folk music of the British Isles. I wonder if this is only a coincidence...

Comment: I've never heard of Qualls, but I would dismiss it on the basis of this account. _The oldest of the English dialects_ is a meaningless phrase. It makes as much sense as _the bluest of the English dialects_ or _the most circular of the English dialects_.

Comment: I believe "oldest" here is intended to mean some combination of age of the dialect in England it was derived from and degree of change (or lack thereof) from that dialect. Looking at the actual research cited would confirm that. Given that reading, I believe the quote is entirely correct.

Comment: By "oldest" I mean "that has been spoken in the Américas longer than any other variety"

Comment: The question does make sense. According to Margery Fee, Department of English, The University of British Columbia, Vancouver, B.C., Canada, one of the varieties spoken in the Américas was brought from England around 1504, much earlier than any other. That's why I want to hear what other sources say about the subject.  http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780192800619.001.0001/acref-9780192800619-e-840?rskey=mUAT9K&result=844

Comment: Ah, well, that's just a matter of who landed when, not whether their dialect -- whatever it might have been -- is still spoken the same way today.

Comment: @Luis abundant fisheries off the coast of Canada brought fishing ships from Europe to reap the rich harvest there.  A French ship arrived in 1504, the date you cite.  For the next 400 years, ships of many nationalities came from Europe to these waters to fish.  Over those years, some people settled in places like Newfoundland, mostly French-speaking but a few English-speaking, but usually would only settle for a year or two then return to Europe.  See [Heritage website](http://www.heritage.nf.ca/society/french_settlement.html).  The Newfoundland language today is far from 1504 English.

Comment: @Brillig NEWFOUNDLAND ENGLISH - The English Language as used in the island and province of Newfoundland for almost 500 years, and the oldest variety in the Américas.  It derives primarily from the speech of early settlers from the English West Country and later Ireland, and is the outcome of long, stable settlement and relative remoteness.  The isolation, however, should not be overemphasized: "The women in these communities were isolated, while the men were not, because they travelled to find

Comment: seasonal work, sealing, logging, and cod-fishing.  [Dictionary of Newfoundland English, 1982.](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780192800619.001.0001/acref-9780192800619-e-840?rskey=WuybDb&result=1)

Comment: @Brillig  Your link leads to French Settlement, which is not what the question is about.  As for your comment,"The Newfoundland Language today is far from 1504 English." I wouldn't say that.  Not after reading a few articles on the subject. Expressions that are archaic or obsolete elsewhere are still heard in the island: -  "angishore",  "bavin",  "brewis",  "bedlamer",  "dotard", "screech", "a livyer", "a come-from-away", in addition to several words for natural phenomena, occupations and activities.

Comment: @Luis I'm aware of the claim made about Newfoundland which is why I specifically mentioned that I could enter into a big debate about whether Newfoundland might be the oldest dialect in North America in my original answer above.  I think the claims about Newfoundland are incorrect for the reason I stated, namely that especially early on it wasn't a permanent settlement, and once people started to settle there was a steady stream of settlers over hundreds of years, so that's hardly a fixed dialect from 1504.  There are other reasons as well that I and many researchers reject these claims.

Comment: @Luis in the link I provided you will see it also talks about the English speaking settlers.  For instance, "The English, meanwhile, were active on Newfoundland's east coast between Cape Bonavista and Cape Race."  I think it's important for you to realize that the vast majority of settlers were French, and how close the French and English settlements really were, because that's another reason the English settlers were not isolated, as your source claims, but instead their dialect was influenced by the French language, as well as most settlers came from much later time periods, not 1504.

Comment: just for some fun: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqLuIXwsLDw

Comment: M. Fee also says that Newfoundland English is more than a dialect of CanE, and can be accepted as a variety with a standard and dialects of its own.

Comment: @Luis "brewis" is derived from French.  "bedlamer" is derived from French and didn't enter the language until around 1760.  "screech" is common to many dialects in the Americas.  "livyer" is a word specific to Newfoundland and is not used in England.  "come-from-away" is common all along the Atlantic coast of Canada and Maine and Terry Pratt traces the first written reference to the 1970s.  None of these are good support for maintaining 1504 English.

Comment: @Brillig        Can you offer any more references about the Appalachian Dialect being the oldest in the Américas ?  I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Luis  Yes, reluctantly, because as I stated in my answer, I really believe that *no* dialect is really oldest, *all* are in transition.  As this [book](http://lrc.ohio.edu/lrcmedia/Streaming/lingCALL/ling270/myth9.pdf) argues, certain anomolies in the Appalachian dialect have encouraged romantic exagerations.  However, it is true that some of these anomolies are truly tied to older forms of the language that are no longer found in standard English, as this [essay](http://whitney.ling.yale.edu/~zanuttini/publications/bernsteinzanuttini2010.pdf) describes.

Comment: @ColinFine I've rewritten and edited the question. If you find it appropriate, I need one reopening vote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16963/discussion-between-luis-and-brillig).